# elasticsearch with 2 tables

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, doctrine

I am using elasticsearch with FOSUserBundle in symfony 2. I have two tables: care provider and score. this are now the structure of the table.

```
-------------------          ------------------
| care provider   |          |  score          |
|                 |          | care_provider_id|
|  id             |          | score           |
|first_name       |          -------------------
| and so on       |
-------------------
```

I dont know how to apply this on elasticsearch, join the care provider table to score table? is this possible? thank you. I am a beginner in using elasticsearch by the way. thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [FOSElasticaBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle). It's a symfony bundle that provides integration with Elasticsearch and Elastica.

With this bundle you can configure elasticsearch with your entity relationship.

For example:

```
fos_elastica:
    indexes:
        app:
            types:
                care_provider:
                    properties:
                        id: { boost: 5 }
                        first_name: { boost: 3 }
                        ...: ~
                        score:
                            type: "object"
```